# Can a coil gun be made with a boost converter instead of caps?

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, electromagnetism, high-voltage

So I’ve been starting to build a coilgun, and I find most designs either have capacitors or are just really bad. But could a high-voltage boost converter (40000v) and a momentary switch not be used to the same effect as long as you pressed and released the switch very quickly? It would eliminate charge times and be a whole lot cheaper, but I assume there is a reason people have not already done it? I am not very experienced in this field, but from my point of view I think this would work. Can someone who actually knows what they are doing help me out?

Comment: Imagine placing a propeller on a bullet. Instead of having some explosive. That's what you're doing to the bullet while it is in the barrel.

Comment: @HarrySvensson so you’re saying it would be too weak?

Comment: Coil guns and rail guns make implicit use of banks of capacitors. Both need KJ to 100MJ of power in just 1 second. Only a charged capacitor bank can deliver so may joules in an instant.

Comment: @Jeffreythesliderturtle There's a wall between you and me at the moment. I can't say anything. - But here's something you might understand. Kick a ball with two different ways, one way of running up to the ball, charging back your leg and then giving it a real good kick. Then grab the ball, place it down, stand right next to the ball. Place your foot against the ball. Now push your foot against the ball as hard as you can. Which of the two "kicks" made the ball go furthest? The one where you could charge up and make a real kick? Or the one where you more or less pushed the ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coil gun lives on the current flow.  A capacitor can deliver hundreds of amperes - though for a very short time.

The short time thing is important.  You need a pulse that starts, accelerates the slug, then dies before the slug reaches the point in the coil where the magnetic field would start decelerating the slug.

A boost converter that can deliver current pulses high enough to do any good is the diametric opposite of simple and cheap.

Using a mechanical switch for that kind of thing is the next best to useless.  If you do it by hand, you'll never get consistent results.  The current would probably weld the contacts of any switch you could come up with.

So, there are plenty of good reasons NOT to use a boost converter - at least not the way you are thinking of it.

Any coil gun you build uses something to generate a high voltage to charge the capacitor - a form of boost converter, if you will.  So in that sense, all coil guns use some form of boost converter.

---

Lets rephrase that:

All coil guns use a boost converter of some kind.  They (slowly) charge a large bank of capacitors because a boost converter that could charge them quickly wouldn't be cheap to build.    A boost converter that could deliver the current needed to drive a coil gun directly would be insane - and probably incorporate a capacitor as big as the typical capacitor banks used in coil guns anyway.

Comment: "*A boost converter that can deliver current pulses high enough to do any good is the diametric opposite of simple and cheap.*", also, it would most certainly use many large capacitors which OP thinks he doesn't need.

Comment: So I guess I’m stuck with capacitors after all, and I’ve read a microwave one won’t work. I guess I’ll just try to find some for a decent price on amazon or mouser. Thanks for clearing that up though

Comment: No reason why linear bank of switched caps charged by light bulbs from rectified AC wont work with a coil of suitable design with  rail contacts having that allow the L/R=T Discharge time as it moves over each contact of separately charged caps of suitable material like silver tungsten alloy

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, that's not what I had in mind tbh. I was thinking what if instead of using capacitors, we use the boosters to charge up the coils themselves directly? And after they're fully charged, we let go off the projectile and the emf of the terminals of the coils would push huge amount of current when we switch off the booster creating a stronger field for a short pulse. Would that charging up coils concept even work?

Comment: @Beyondo:  The current through a coil is never higher than the current you used to "charge" it.  If you apply current at 1 ampere to the coil, then only one ampere will flow in the coil when you shut off the power.  The voltage will go up, but the current will not.